# UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath not registering cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uicollectionview

I am trying to use `UICollectionViewCell`, since all I want to display is an image. I can add the image to the cell using `UIColor colorWithImage:` on the `UICollectionViewCell`'s `contentView` property.

In my `loadView` method, I am registering the cell as follows:
`[self.collectionView registerClass:[ImageCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];`

Below is my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // cell customization
    return cell;
}
```

When I run it, as soon as it hits the dequeue line, it crashes with the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:]

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier MyCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

I tired setting up a custom cell, and used it as the class and I got the same error. My custom cell subclassed UICollectionViewCell and had nothing implemented, except for the default `initWithFrame`. That is because I wanted to just change the background colour of the view. I am not sure what the problem is but could someone please take a look at my code and help me? I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while with absolutely no luck at all.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you just want to display an image, you don't need to do any subclassing, you can set the cell's `backgroundColor` with `colorWithPatternImage:`. Register the class like this:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Then use it like so:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

In this example, results is an `array` of `UIImages`.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using xib in applivation then add following in your viewdidLoad method

```
    [self.myCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
```

otherwise If you using storyboard add following

```
  [self.myCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
```

Finally add this (If not)

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 return cell;
}
```

Hope above will help.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your first snippet was what I was looking for :)

Comment: I'm using storyboard & mt custom cell isn't dequeue any idea?

Comment: @OfirMalachi please check for reusable cell identifier.

Answer (score 8):

Try setting a breakpoint on

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[ImageCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
```

I would guess your loadView (did you mean viewDidLoad?) method is not being called, so the class is never registered with the collectionView.

Answer (score 7):

if your collection view is connected on storyboard and the delegate and datasource is set there, and you provide the necessary methods for the datasource and delegate, then adding the register call makes the

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

return a `UICollectionView` instead of your own subclass of it. So do either but not both.

Comment: If you want to use Xib, you can find the answer in this document [UICollectionView adding UICollectionCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184968/uicollectionview-adding-uicollectioncell).

Answer (score 4):

set your cell identifier name as in code

[image]

Comment: Yes this along with registering the collection view in viewDidLoad did the trick. I did manage to cause myself some grief in the dequeue call for a while. I had "Cell ", i.e. with an extraneous blank, which is of course not the same as "Cell", so be very very careful about your names.