# UICollectionVIew without using the storyboard?

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview

I read through these tutorials on UICollectionView:

http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/paul-dakessian/ios-6-tutorial-getting-started-collection-views

http://invasivecode.tumblr.com/post/34581461219/an-introduction-to-collection-views.

I know it's easy to use the CollectionView in storyboard, but I want to use the UICollectionView with a xib instead of a storyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So... do you want to create one in code or do you want to create one in a XIB?

Comment: What's your question? What exactly are you having an issue with?

Comment: yes i want to add the uicollectionview in my xib

Comment: @rmaddy i want to use the uicollectionview like UIVIew -> UIcollectionview ->uicollectionview cell then after i want to add image in uicollectionview cell but i can not add image in uicollectionview cell

Comment: This might help you https://github.com/lequysang/TestCollectionViewWithXIB   This is a another stack link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184968/uicollectionview-adding-uicollectioncell

Comment: Can you include some code? How far are you getting? Is the problem just in populating the cells, or do you not even see cells?

Answer (score 11):

This is another stackoverflow link :

[UICollectionView adding UICollectionCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184968/uicollectionview-adding-uicollectioncell)

This is one Github project:

https://github.com/lequysang/TestCollectionViewWithXIB

Comment: I'll give you a plus one, although in general "link only" answers (without much further detail or elaboration) are not encouraged here.

Answer (score 5):

A XIB file usually contains exactly one view controller (and many objects as part of that view controller).

And a storyboard is (for all intents and purposes) essentially a collection of XIB files all strung together by segues, so you can follow the flow.

What you really want to do here is simply substitute the word "XIB" for the word "Storyboard" in pretty much any tutorial you're looking at, keeping in mind that without a storyboard, you won't be using segues to get from view controller to the next view controller.

[And here's a UICollectionView tutorial that you can refer to, which happens to talk about xib files, to boot](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/).  I hope this info helps you out!