# UICollectionViewCell doesn't draw child view

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I've met strange issue: I have subclassed UICollectionViewCell with UIImageView as its child. This cell doesn't draw (collection view looks clear) but it catches touches. Also, child UIImageView looks visible in Interface Builder. If I override cell's 'drawRect:' method, it draws my custom drawing code.

What is reason that UIImageView doesn't draw? I test it on iOS 6 and 7.

Following code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSAssert (cell != nil, @"MyCollectionViewCell init failed"); // all right here
    cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImage"]; // this line doesn't matter
    return cell;
}

...
@implementation LookCollectionViewCell
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect: rect];
    [[UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 0 blue: 0 alpha:1] setFill];
    UIRectFill(CGRectInset(rect, 10, 10)); // draws red rect on black background
}
@end
```

**Update:**

If I initialize collection view cell in code via 'initWithFrame:' and add 'UIImageView' manually, all works fine. So, the problem is that collection view cell from Interface Builder doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this simply doesn't work if `UICollectionViewCell` is a child of `UICollectionView` in Interface Builder.

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15185028/326017 "You cannot put UICollectionViewCell directly into the UiCollectionView if you are using Xib file."

So if I use separate XIB file for cell and register it via `[collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];` all works fine.