# What's the point of setting Reuse Identifier for Collection View Cell in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Collection Reusable Views, including Collection View Cells (which is a subclass), have a field in Interface Builder called "Identifier" with prompt "Reuse Identifier".

However, you normally use it by registering it with the `UICollectionView` using the `–registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` and `–registerNib:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:` methods, where you also specify a reuse identifier.

So then what's the point of setting one in Interface Builder? It seems to make no difference whether you set it there or not.

Answer (score 4):

If you implicitly load a collection view from a storyboard you only have to do

```
UICollectionView *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to get the cell. You don't need to call `registerNib:`. This only works if you set a reuse identifier.

Answer (score 2):

For NibCell (UICollectionView in a Nib) you must use registerNib:, that's only way.
If you give your Cell in Nib a reuse identifier, this identifier must same in register so better leave it blank.

-Cell by Code: registerClass

-Cell in Nib(Xib) registerNib

-Cell in StoryBoard: don't register

One more answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184968/uicollectionview-adding-uicollectioncell/15185034#15185034)

Comment: This is helpful

Answer (score 0):

In the viewDidLoad of viewContoller
     register class or Nib of uicollectionview with Reuse Identifier
and use the same in

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

yes i agree it makes no difference to setting in the Interface Bulider but if set in the Interface Builder and use a different in your code than it would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a situation myself where there most definitely *is* a difference in behaviour between having the reuse identifier set in Interface Builder and *not* having it set. *(This is along the lines of what @LESANG is alluding to in their answer; that the reuse identifier should be left blank when creating cells in a separate nib file. I wanted to include some more details of when/why this is the case)*

In my case, I had a custom cell that I wanted to be usable by multiple different view controllers. In order to share the cell, I created a separate nib file for the cell, configured the view hierarchy, **and assigned a reuse identifier in Interface Builder**. Each view controller then registers the cell using `register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)`, and passing in the same reuse identifier as set in IB.

However, for one of my view controllers, I actually wanted to register different cells (different reuse identifiers) but using the same nib*. But simply passing in a different reuse identifier causes the app to crash, complaining:

> view reuse identifier in nib (`<reuse identifier in nib>`) does not match the identifier used to register the nib (`<reuse identifier when registering programmatically>`)

So to solve this, **there must be no reuse identifier specified in the nib itself**. By removing the identifier in the nib, the identifier specified in `register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)` is used instead, and cells are dequeued correctly.

It's worth noting, therefore, that when defining cells in nib files, there appears to be no point whatsoever in coding the reuse identifier into the nib – any views that want to use that cell must register it manually in code anyway, at which point the reuse identifier specified *there* might as well be used rather than the one in the nib. In this scenario, it seems that all the identifier in the nib does is take precedence over the programmatically registered identifier, and cause a crash should you attempt to use a different identifier.

---

**Sure, I could create a new nib file with the same/similar view hierarchy and a different reuse identifier, but then should I need to change the cell configuration I'd have to make the same change across multiple files.*